# Separation of view and logic in flutter widget

Tags: flutter

I have been programming with C# for many years and use Pattern MVVM.

I would like to switch to Flutter, but I have a few basic questions. I would like to start with one here:

I can only find examples where the events are programmed inside widget. For example:

```
    onPressed: () {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: { context.
          return AlertDialog(
            // Retrieve the text that user has entered by using the
            // TextEditingController.
            content: Text(myController.text),
          );
        },
      );
    },
```

But I am usual to separate the view from the logic of the program. Therefore, because then the programming is clear and the maintenance of the program is also much easier.

Is this also the case with Flutter and if so, what would the code look like (because I haven't found an example). I imagine it then in such a way:

```
    onPressed: () {
          showDialog()
    },
```

method:

```
static showDialog()
{
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                // Retrieve the text that user has entered by using the
                // TextEditingController.
                content: Text(myController.text),
              );
            },
          );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally your approach is correct, but

```dart
onPressed: () {
   showDialog()
},
```

the problem here is that showDialog() depends on the BuildContext `context` which is usually only available inside a widget. The `context` here is used to create the AlertDialog. In this case it would not really be possible to extract that showDialog method unless you pass the context as a parameter.

So if your method you want to extract modifies the UI in some form (like show a dialog) I would keep it there.

But for everything else, like fetching Data from an API when a button is pressed you could extract that method.

```dart
void fetchData() {
 ...
}

...
onPressed: fetchData, // same as '() => fetchData()'  or '() {fetchData();}'
...
```

Here you would need to think about how you get the data back in the UI. I would probably use a callback that updates the state of the widget once the data is fetched.